# jQuery fn.extend ({bla: function(){}} vs. jQuery.fn.bla

Tags: jquery, performance, syntax, jquery-plugins, extend

OK I think I get
[Difference between jQuery.extend and jQuery.fn.extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991126/difference-jquery-extend-and-jquery-fn-extend)

in that the general extend can extend any object, and that fn.extend is for plugin functions that can be invoked straight off the jquery object with some internal jquery voodoo.

So it appears one would invoke them differently.  If you use general extend to extend object  obj by adding function y, then the method  would attach to that object,   obj.y()  but if you use fn.extend then they are
attach straight to the jquery object $.y().... Have I got that correct yes or no and if no what do I have wrong in my understanding?

### Now MY question:

The book I am reading advocates using

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    a: function() { },
    b: function() { }
});
```

syntax but in the docs it says

```
jQuery.fn.a = function() { };
```

and I guess if you wanted b as well it would be

```
jQuery.fn.b = function() { };
```

Are these functionally and performance-wise equivalent and if not what is the difference?

Thank you very much.  I am digging jQuery!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's very subtle difference between them. Performance wise (not that this is an issue), `jQuery.fn.extend` is going to be slower than directly declaring a function like `jQuery.fn.foo = function(){ };`. I'm talking **completely negligible difference**.

The difference is `jQuery.fn.extend()` allows you to add multiple plugin functions simultaneously and might make your code look a little cleaner depending on what type of plugin you're authoring.

---

```
jQuery.fn.a = function(){};
jQuery.fn.b = function(){};
```

Is exactly the same as

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  a: function(){ },
  b: function(){ }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Both ways are almost identical. However, some small differences exist, in the following aspects -

1. **Speed**
2. **Code style**
3. **Naming your plugin elsewhere**

**Speed** :

Negligible. You may ignore this aspect since it is unlikely you will notice performance differences between the two.

**Code style** :

the extend version adheres to the Object literal code style, which may seem a bit more elegant for some. For instance, if your plug-in uses the Object literal abundantly, you might prefer wrapping it using $.extend({}).

**Naming your plugin elsewhere** :

There is one other (significant, in my opinion) advantage in using the $.fn.a style - you can store your plugin's name elsewhere, anywhere in your code, then use its reference when adding the plugin to jQuery's namespace. This cannot be done when extending using an object literal. This advantage is somewhat relative to the length of your code, and to the number of occurrences of the plugin's name. One also might argue that the average coder rarely changes the name of his plugin, and if he does, it won't take long in most cases.

*Example* :

```
;(function($) {

    // Declare your plugin's name here
    var PLUGIN_NS = 'myPluginName';

    // ... some arbitrary code here ...

    // The jQuery plugin hook
    $.fn[ PLUGIN_NS ] = function( args ) {

        if ( $.type(args) !== 'object' )
            var args = {};

        var options = $.extend({}, $.fn[ PLUGIN_NS ].defaults, args);

        // iterate over each matching element
        return this.each({
            var obj = $(this);

            // we can still use PLUGIN_NS inside the plugin
            obj.data( PLUGIN_NS+'Data' , args );

            // ... rest of plugin code ...
        });

    };

    // ----------------
    // PRIVATE defaults
    // ----------------

    var defaults = {
        foo: 1,
        bar: "bar"
    };

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // PUBLIC defaults
    // returns a copy of private defaults.
    // public methods cannot change the private defaults var.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------

    // we can use PLUGIN_NS outside the plugin too.
    $.fn[ PLUGIN_NS ].defaults = function() {
        return $.extend({}, defaults);
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Now we can call the plugin, and defaults, like so:

```
$("div#myDiv").myPluginName({foo:2});
var originalFoo = $("div#myDiv").myPluginName.defaults().foo;
```

To change the plugin's name, change the *PLUGIN_NS* var.
This may be preferable over changing each occurrence of *myPluginName* inside the plugin code.

Comment: Actually you need to override defaults by using "args" parameter.