# Is it bad practice to use $.extend for general helper functions?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my AgularJs project I need serveral functions in different parts of the project (for example functions to sort Arrays in a special way, compare values in a special way, and such).

As there are already so many Services in my app, I am kind of reluctant to use another one to make those functions available in every part of my project.

So I came up with the idea to use `$.extend` to extend the jQuery namespace by custom functions like

```
$.extend({
    myHelperFunctions : {
        sortMyArrayInThatSpecialWay: function(array) {

            ...
            return sortedArray;
        },
        ...
    }
});
```

That way its possible to use

```
var sortedArray = $.myHelperFunctions.sortMyArrayInThatSpecialWay(unsortedArray);
```

In every controller, service or any other function in my application, without haveing to inject a service.

Now my question is: Is that good practice? And if not, why?

Comment: Why would it be bad? I think jQuery actually encourage it, for example: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#accepting-options

Comment: I hope you have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609951/jquery-fn-extend-bla-function-vs-jquery-fn-bla)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `$.extend` that way. In fact, `jQuery.fn.extend` just calls `jQuery.extend` internally on the prototype of jQuery itself. The difference from declaring properties directly will never ever be noticeable.

Comment: This is bad for the same reason why the use of jQuery in Angular can be bad. Using jQuery namespace for everything is antipattern. The purpose of DI is to avoid globals and coupling, not to propagate them. Btw, there are `angular.extend`, and idiomatic `Object.assign` already.

Comment: @estus, can you provide further reading to your argument?

Comment: Not so much. Most times the one can truly understand design issue only when it shows itself and creates a problem. But for example, https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/top-10-mistakes-angularjs-developers-make#3-dependency-injection . And 'sortMyArrayInThatSpecialWay' should likely be a method of some class rather than standalone helper.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, `jQuery.extend` is going to be slower than directly declaring a function like `jQuery.fn.foo = function(){ };`

So it would be better to define the function and use it that way.

Here is a tiny example I can provide to support my answer:

```
jQuery.log = function(message) {
    // log somewhere
};

$.log("much better");
```