# How to make my function get invoked by $(..).name()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a js function named `draw()`, now is it possible that I can call this method using `.` operator after I get the element using `$(...)`. I mean I like this to work `$(#myId).draw()`. Right now it gives error like undefined function. How can I make it work?

Comment: Are you looking for invoking the method like a jquery function?

Comment: @RaviH : yes, just like default methods.

Comment: Then read about how to write a jquery plugin and make it a jquery plugin.

Comment: @WesleyMurch yes it seems duplicate though I am not making any plugin :P. I will mark it as.

Comment: The `.` operator is not directly related to "invoking functions", excepting as it can affect the context. `$(..).draw()` simple tries to invoke the function-object returned from the `draw` property of the jQuery object which was returned by `$(..)`.. in your case, the property doesn't exist and yields `undefined` which cause the exception to be thrown. The correct way to implement such a feature in this case, as pointed out, is to create a jQuery plugin or "extension".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to add methods using jquery.fn.extend ( As we can add several plugin functions at a time )

Sample code looks like

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  draw: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      // add code here to draw
    });
  }
});
```

Once you add this method, you can use below code to call your draw method on any jQuery element

```
$("#myId").draw()
```

**Official Reference:** [jquery.fn.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/)

Comment: out of interest, is there any reason that `fn.extend` is better than `fn.draw = ...`?

Comment: @Eru The jQuery.fn.extend is used to extend the jQuery.fn object, which in fact adds several plugin functions at a time.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want to create a *jQuery plugin*.  You can do that by extending `$.fn`:

```
$.fn.draw = function(){
    /* ... */
}
```

Then you can call that against a selector:

```
$('#myId').draw();
```

More documentation here: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1):

You have to create it as a jquery plugin. As described here.

[Best Way to Extend a jQuery Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050985/best-way-to-extend-a-jquery-plugin)

Documentation from jQuery:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

JsFiddle sample: http://jsfiddle.net/Wdx75/

```
var obj1 = { "color" : "yellow" };
var obj2 = { "background" : "blue" };

var o = $.extend({}, obj1, obj2);


$.fn.draw = function(){
    $("div").css(o);
}

$('abc').draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll neet to [look at adding](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/02/converting-jquery-code-plugin/) a [jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523264/jquery-plugin-converting-functions-into-a-plugin)

```
$.fn.draw= function(){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `jQuery.fn.extend`, documented here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/.

```
$.fn.extend({
    draw: function() {

    // do something to the jQuery object
    return this;

    }
});
```

Now you can call `.draw` on a jQuery object created with `$(...)`.