# jQuery.extend() and jQuery.fn.extend() are the same… Right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

I was examining the query source code when I came across this:

```
3730     |  jQuery.extend({
3731-3775|      //code
3776     |  });
```

And then right after that, I found this:

```
3778| jQuery.fn.extend({
----|    //code
----| })
```

These two should be the same because back on line `296` where the extend function is declared, I found this:

```
296| jQuery.extend = jQuery.fn.extend = function() {
```

But since they are the same, why would the jQuery team suddenly switch from always using `jQuery.extend()` to suddenly using `jQuery.fn.extend()`?

Comment: They are not the same, read the documentation.

Comment: $.fn.extend = Merge the contents of an object onto the jQuery prototype to provide new jQuery instance methods.

Comment: jQuery.extend = Merge the contents of two or more objects together into the first object.

Comment: the plugin methods(on, val, $('item').map(), etc) are created using `$.fn.extend` where are static methods($.map, $.each, etc) are created using `$.extend`

Comment: If they're different, what about the assignment on line 296?

Comment: I could definitely mark some of these as correct answers if they were answers...

Comment: @Barmar it is operating on the context in which it is called upon... in the case of `$.extend()` `this` inside the extend method refer to the `$` object where as `$.fn.extend` `this` refers to the `$.fn` object where all the plugins are stored so the context of the calls are different

Comment: @Saravana Oh no! I didn't see that!

Comment: @Progo: I just wanted to copy [my answer from there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14819896/1048572) to here :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.extend` simply extends an object

```
var obj1 = {'name' : 'Progo'};
var obj2 = {'value' : 'stack overflow'};

$.extend(obj1, obj2);

// obj1 is now {'name' : 'Progo', 'value' : 'stack overflow'}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ut2Y5/)

`jQuery.fn.extend` extends the jQuery prototype

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  turn_red: function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      this.style.color = 'red'
    });
  }
});

// gives you

$('elements').turn_red(); // sets color to red
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ut2Y5/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The key difference is here:

```
// extend jQuery itself if only one argument is passed
if ( length === i ) {
    target = this;
    --i;
}
```

`this` will be different depending on whether `$.extend` or `$.fn.extend` was called.

Comment: You even could call `$.extend()` with only one argument…