# Understanding jQuery return object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to understand how jQuery creates the return object when searching for DOM elements. I've gone through the source, but I'm not completely sure I understand, and was hoping somebody here could give me some insight.

From what I can gather reading the source, when querying for a jQuery DOM, jQuery finds matching DOM elements, and then adds the matched DOM element as an object using the index of the element as the key for the new object.

```
if ( rsingleTag.test( match[1] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
    for ( match in context ) {
       // Properties of context are called as methods if possible
       if ( jQuery.isFunction( this[ match ] ) ) {
             this[ match ]( context[ match ] );    
            // ...and otherwise set as attributes
       } else {
            this.attr( match, context[ match ] );
       }
    }
}    
return this;
```

Returning `this`, is returning the entire jQuery object which includes all the methods. Have I got it right to this point?

Now, it appears all the functions like css,find,ajax,hide,etc. are in the jQuery.fn object.

Somehow (and I think this is where I'm not seeing it), these functions are called, not on the DOM element itself, but through the access.js 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/access.js

```
var access = jQuery.access = function( elems, fn, key, value, chainable, emptyGet, raw ) {
```

using css as an example, we have

```
jQuery.extend({
    css: function( elem, name, extra, styles ) {...

jQuery.fn.extend({
css: function( name, value ) {
        return access( this, function( elem, name, value ) {
            var styles, len,
                map = {},
                i = 0;

            if ( jQuery.isArray( name ) ) {
                styles = getStyles( elem );
                len = name.length;

                for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
                    map[ name[ i ] ] = jQuery.css( elem, name[ i ], false, styles );
                }

                return map;
            }

            return value !== undefined ?
                jQuery.style( elem, name, value ) :
                jQuery.css( elem, name );
        }, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
```

What I think I'm missing is how did we get from calling `$('div').css(...)` to that calling the jQuery.fn.extend.css method, and from there, the access method being called with a different signature to the access method initialized in the core jQuery?

Also, if we're constantly replacing the `jQuery[0],jQuery[1]`, how is it that I can have:

```
var divs = $('div');
var spans = $('span');
```

Maintaining two different set of document tags if they are both returning the same jQuery object? I thought the object would be updated.

Am I completely misunderstanding how this is all working?

Comment: What about "step by step" approach with the debugger ? `:/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From what I can gather reading the source, when querying for a jQuery
>   DOM, jQuery finds matching DOM elements, and then adds the matched DOM
>   element as an object using the index of the element as the key for the
>   new object.

Yes. jQuery instances are basically array-like objects.

> ```
> if ( rsingleTag.test( match[1] ) && jQuery.isPlainObject( context ) ) {
>     for ( match in context ) {
>        // Properties of context are called as methods if possible
>        if ( jQuery.isFunction( this[ match ] ) ) {
>              this[ match ]( context[ match ] );    
>             // ...and otherwise set as attributes
>        } else {
>             this.attr( match, context[ match ] );
>        }
>     }
> }    
> return this;
> ```

But that's not what happens in this cited section of the code. What you see here is the code for handling the [`jQuery(html, attributes)` signature](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) - when the second argument is an object and the first is standalone html tag, then call the respective methods or set the attributes on the new collection (`this`).

> Returning this, is returning the entire jQuery object which includes
>   all the methods. Now, it appears all the functions like css,find,ajax,hide,etc. are in
>   the jQuery.fn object.

Yes. The objects that are returned by the jQuery constructor do inherit these methods from the [`$.fn` prototype object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083351/what-does-jquery-fn-mean).

> Somehow (and I think this is where I'm not seeing it), these functions
>   are called, not on the DOM element itself, but through the access.js
>   https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/access.js

`access` is just an internal helper function. All the jQuery methods are called on jQuery instances.

> using css as an example, we have
>
> ```
> jQuery.extend({
>     css: function( elem, name, extra, styles ) {...
> ```

`jQuery.css()` is just a "static", internal helper function for getting computed css values. Nothing you'd ever directly use yourself.

> ```
> jQuery.fn.extend({
>     css: function( name, value ) {
>         return access( this, function( elem, name, value ) {
>             …
>         }, name, value, arguments.length > 1 );
>     }
> ```
>
> What I think I'm missing is how did we get from calling
>   $('div').css(...) to that calling the jQuery.fn.extend.css method

There is no `jQuery.fn.extend.css` method. That call to [`jQuery.fn.extend()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1991126/1048572) does *define* the `jQuery.fn.css` method. And that's just the method you call - it's prototypically inherited by `$('div')`.

> and from there, the access method being called with a different signature
>   to the access method initialized in the core jQuery?

No, why do you think that?

```
// the signature:
access = function( elems, fn, key, value, chainable, emptyGet, raw )
// the call:
access( this, // array-like collection
        function(…){…}, // callback
        name, // string
        value, // whatever
        arguments.length > 1 // boolean whether it's a getter
        // undefined, implicit
        // undefined, implicit
      )
```

> Also, if we're constantly replacing the jQuery[0],jQuery[1]

No, we aren't? Where did you see that?

> how is it that I can have: `var divs = $('div'); var spans = $('span');`
>   Maintaining two different set of document tags if they are both
>   returning the same jQuery object?

They aren't. Both calls do create new jQuery instances.

> I thought the object would be updated.

No, jQuery instances are quite immutable.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, so I am correct in thinking that every time you do a dom query, jQuery creates a new jQuery instance? That doesn't seem super efficient to me.

Comment: Well, you don't do (shouldn't be doing?) DOM queries so often anyway. The overhead of a new jQuery instance is actually quite small compared to the query itself, and creating immutable collections eases chaining and functional composition. Mutating them can lead to ugly bugs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm not actually using jQuery, but building a system similar to jQuery so want to learn by following their style.