# jQuery extending $.fn with an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Using this [Difference between jQuery.extend and jQuery.fn.extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991126/difference-between-jquery-extend-and-jquery-fn-extend) Is there a way to have something like `$('.selector').Group.Method();` and `$('.selector').Group.Method2();`

Right now I have a this in a main script

```
function Forty() {};

var Forty = new Forty();

(function(site) {
    $.extend(Forty, {
        getBaseUrl: function(extra) {
            extra = typeof extra !== 'undefined' ? extra : '';
            return Forty.get('baseUrl') + extra;
        },
        get: function($what) {
            return site[$what];
        }
    });
})(site);
```

Then later in that file I have:

```
$.extend(Forty, {
    flyOut: function() {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            $('html').toggleClass('nav-open');
        });
    }
});
```

And at the very end I have:

```
$.fn.extend({Forty: Forty});
```

Right before I have this line:

```
$('.selector').Forty.flyOut();
```

So I'd really like something like `$('.selector').Forty.flyOut();`

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Yes, but you'll probably have to refactor your code. The word you need to google is "chaining" wrt jQuery plugins.

Comment: `var Forty = new Forty();` is a very, very bad idea.

Comment: And, **NO**, it's [possible but you shouldn't do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15884096/organize-prototype-javascript-while-perserving-object-reference-and-inheritance)

Comment: That's the case with Prototype, would this be the same with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this, by going:

```
var Forty = {fn:{}};

$.fn.extend({Forty: function() {return $.extend(this, Forty.fn);}});
```

Then assigning my own functions like so:

```
Forty.fn.flyOut = function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $('html').toggleClass('nav-open');
    });

    return this;
}
```

and using them like:

```
$('.js-toggle-nav').Forty().flyOut();
```

This seemed to work epicly!