# How to replicate a jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to write my own functions similar to jquery?
For example:

```
$('parameter1').doSomething('parameter2);

function $(p1){
   var doSomething=function(p2){}; // this does not work to call....

}
```

Comment: What is `parameter1` ? , what is `parameter2` ? , what is expected result ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991126/difference-between-jquery-extend-and-jquery-fn-extend

Comment: I wanted to write like jquery: $("any parameter").action("second parameter); 
How do i write this to work in JS (no Jquery)? Thank you.

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js , https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/init.js

Comment: i saw it but still does not seem what i want. The define function is part os RequireJS. Not standard JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `$` as property of global `window` object ; creating an object `obj` within `$()` function having property `doSomething` , setting `window.$` to object `obj` ; creating an alias for `window.$` utilizing a namespace; return `window.$` object having property `.doSomething`  from call to `$()`

```js
window.$ = function $(args) {
  var obj = {
    doSomething: function doSomething(args) {
      // do stuff
      document.write(args + "\n");
      console.log(this);
      // return `window.$`
      return window.$
    }
  };
  // create alias for `window.$`
  var namespace = "abc";
  // set `window.$` to `obj`
  window.$ = window[namespace] = obj;
  if (args && window.$) {
    window.$.doSomething.call(window.$, args)
  };
  // return `window.$`
  return window.$
};

$("abc").doSomething("def");
```

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to understand the concept of [method chaining](http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html) in JavaScript.

Your `$()` method in the example above doesn't return anything.

Even if it did, the object returned from your `$()` method would also need to have a `doSomething()` method.

For example:

```
$ = function(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

$('foobar').doSomething(); //assumes doSomething() exists on the returned object.
```