# Difference between $.fn and $.fn.extend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I know the difference between `$.fn.extend` and `$.extend`. But what is the difference between `$.fn` and `$.fn.extend`? When should I use one or the other? In the jQuery learning center for implementing jQuery plugins, I cannot find any examples that use `$.fn.extend` or discuss when to use `$.fn.extend` and when to use `$.fn`.

Thank you.

Take a very basic example:

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "green" );
};

$( "a" ).greenify(); // Makes all the links green.

$.fn.extend({
    greenifyP: function() {
        return this.css( "color", "green" );
    }
});

$(  "p" ).greenifyP();


// html
<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
<p>test</p>
```

Are the two methods exactly the same under the covers? I'm trying to determine when would I use `$.fn.extend`, as opposed to `$.fn` and if they are equivalent?

Comment: Review this answer : 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/1991134/5365770
Or
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13992290/5365770

Comment: Maybe start with what you are wanting to do. Assuming you want to put a plugin together. Can declare it several ways and will still do same thing

Comment: In other words .... *different strokes for different folks*