# Creating methods on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, methods

Hi I'm trying to author a jQuery plugin and I need to have methods accessible to elements after they are initialized as that kind of object, e.g.:

```
$('.list').list({some options}); //This initializes .list as a list

//now I want it to have certain methods like:
$('.list').find('List item'); //does some logic that I need
```

I tried with

```
$.fn.list = function (options) {
    return this.each(function() {
        // some code here
        this.find = function(test) {
            //function logic
        }
    }
}
```

and several other different attempts, I just can't figure out how to do it.

EDIT:

I'll try to explain this better.

I'm trying to turn a table into a list, basically like a list on a computer with column headers and sortable items and everything inbetween. You initiate the table with a command like

```
$(this).list({
    data: [{id: 1, name:'My First List Item', date:'2010/06/26'}, {id:2, name:'Second', date:'2010/05/20'}]
});
```

`.list` will make  the `<tbody>` sortable and do a few other initial tasks, then add the following methods to the element:
`.findItem(condition)` will allow you to find a certain item by a condition (like `findItem('name == "Second"')`
`.list(condition)` will list all items that match a given condition
`.sort(key)` will sort all items by a given key
etc.

What's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more of an example? It's hard to say what you're after...and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) is already taken :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods)

Comment: title is misleading, these are not methods created on the fly.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how to explain it exactly. @redsquare thanks for that, I'm going to try doing it that way.

Comment: This is an interesting read about structuring a plugin so you can later access it using the element's data: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-plugin-design-patterns-part-i/ and here is a starter format (http://starter.pixelgraphics.us/ - all by Doug Neiner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution here:
http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/10/building-object-oriented-jquery-plugin.html

This seems to do exactly what I need.

```
(function($) {
    var TaskList = function(element, options)
    {
        var $elem = $(element);
        var options = $.extend({
            tasks: [],
            folders: []
        }, options || {});

        this.changed = false;
        this.selected = {};

        $elem.sortable({
            revert: true,
            opacity: 0.5
        });

        this.findTask = function(test, look) {
            var results = [];

            for (var i = 0,l = options.tasks.length; i < l; i++)
            {
                var t = options['tasks'][i];
                if (eval(test))
                {
                    results.push(options.tasks[i]);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }

        var debug = function(msg) {
            if (window.console) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    $.fn.taskList = function(options)
    {
        return this.each(function() {
            var element = $(this);

            if (element.data('taskList')) { return; }

            var taskList = new TaskList(this, options);

            element.data('taskList', taskList);

        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

Then I have

```
    $('.task-list-table').taskList({
        tasks: eval('(<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($tasks)); ?>)'),
        folders: eval('(<?php echo mysql_real_escape_string(json_encode($folders)); ?>)')
    });
    var taskList = $('.task-list-table').data('taskList');
```

and I can use `taskList.findTask(condition);`

And since the constructor has `$elem` I can also edit the jQuery instance for methods like `list(condition)` etc. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want these methods to be available on any jQuery object, you will have to add each one of them to jQuery's prototype. The reason is every time you call `$(".list")` a fresh new object is created, and any methods you attached to a previous such object will get lost.

Assign each method to jQuery's prototype as:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    list: function() { .. },
    findItem: function() { .. },
    sort: function() { .. }
});
```

The `list` method here is special as it can be invoked on two occasions. First, when initializing the list, and second when finding particular items by a condition. You would have to differentiate between these two cases somehow - either by argument type, or some other parameter.

You can also use the `data` API to throw an exception if these methods are called for an object that has not been initialized with the list plugin. When `('xyz').list({ .. })` is first called, store some state variable in the data cache for that object. When any of the other methods - "list", "findItem", or "sort" are later invoked, check if the object contains that state variable in its data cache.

A better approach would be to namespace your plugin so that `list()` will return the extended object. The three extended methods can be called on its return value. The interface would be like:

```
$('selector').list({ ... });
$('selector').list().findOne(..);
$('selector').list().findAll(..);
$('selector').list().sort();
```

Or save a reference to the returned object the first time, and call methods on it directly.

```
var myList = $('selector').list({ ... });
myList.findOne(..);
myList.findAll(..);
myList.sort();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, that was actually very helpful I finally realize why my methods weren't existing. Couldn't I do `$list = $('.list').list({options});`

and use $list from that point on? Anyway, I found another solution, I'm going to post it as an answer. +1 though thanks

Comment: @Rob - You can do that, as long as inside the `list` method, you extend the jQuery object with all the functions you need, and from this point onwards reference `$list` to call those functions. That said, I think your approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

`this.each` isn't needed. This should do:

```
$.fn.list = function (options) {
    this.find = function(test) {
        //function logic
    };
    return this;
};
```

Note that you'd be overwriting jQuery's native `find` method, and doing so isn't recommended.

---

Also, for what it's worth, I don't think this is a good idea. jQuery instances are assumed to only have methods inherited from jQuery's prototype object, and as such I feel what you want to do would not be consistent with the generally accepted jQuery-plugin behaviour -- i.e. return the `this` object (the jQuery instance) unchanged.

Comment: While I agree *usually*, this isn't always the case, a major example I can think of is the validate plugin...it all depends what your needs are.

Comment: I tried doing just that (changed the .find to .findItem) and ended up with the error $('.list-box').findItem is not a function