# jQuery fire function on all class elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to execute some function on all class elements. How can i do that?**

what i want is something like:

```
// i want to fire my function on all class elements
$('.myClass').go(function(){
    // my function using "this" object
});
```

i know this is a dumb question, i used to work on propotype for some time and now i don't remember proper function for jquery

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Simple:

```
$(".myClass").each(function() {
    ...
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 6):

Just use the common `.each()` iterator:

```
$('.myClass').each(function() {
    go($(this));
});
```

Another option if you're into more elegant code, write your own plugin - good answer can be found in this question: [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods)