# How to create simple jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, plugins, extend

This test plugin, is supposed to work like this: When an element is clicked, it moves down. Simple as that.

```
jQuery.fn.moveDown = function(howMuch){
    $(this).css("border", "1px solid black");
    $(this).click(function(){

        $(this).css("position", "relative");
        $(this).animate({top: '+='+howMuch});
    }); 
}
```

The problem is, when an element is clicked, it not only moves the clicked element but also ALL the other elements which the plugin was applied to.

What is the solution for this?

Comment: I tested this on Chrome, seems to work perfectly well.

Comment: It works. But not as it should. When an element is clicked, all the elements with the plugin applied to, move too. The only element supposed to move is the one that has been clicked.

Comment: Well, that's what I checked.  I applied it to two elements using *$("#el1").moveDown("100px")* and *$("#el2").moveDown("100px")*.  When I clicked an element, only that one moved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For plugin authoring try this way, much more solid:

Edit:
[**Here is working jsFiddle example.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/6/)

---

PLUGIN:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({
        YourPluginName: function(options) {
                var defaults = {
                      howMuch:'600',
                      animation: '',//users can set/change these values
                      speed: 444,
                      etc: ''
                }
        };

       options = $.extend(defaults, options);

       return this.each(function() {
          var $this = $(this);              
          var button = $('a', $this);// this represents all the 'a' selectors;
                                            // inside user's plugin definition.

          button.click(function() {
            $this.animate({'top':options.howMuch});//calls options howMuch value
          });
       });
})(jQuery);
```

USER'S DOCUMENT:

```
$(function() {
   $('#plugin').YourPluginName({
     howMuch:'1000' //you can give chance users to set their options for plugins
   });
});

<div id="plugin">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
  <a>3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice plugin man, I think you're missing a closing `}` for the plugin, anyway really nice work. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/6/) for testing.

Comment: Thanks mate, i saw closing mistake and edited that. it was on; `var defaults = {`

Answer (score 0):

Here i want to suggest steps to create simple plugin with arguments.

**JS**

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myFirstPlugin = function( options ) {

        // Default params
        var params = $.extend({
            text     : 'Default Title',
            fontsize : 10,
        }, options);
        return $(this).text(params.text);

    }
}(jQuery));
```

Here, we have added default object called `params` and set default values of options using `extend` function. Hence, If we pass blank argument then it will set default values instead otherwise it will set.

**HTML**

```
$('.cls-title').myFirstPlugin({ text : 'Argument Title' });
```

**Read more:** [How to Create JQuery plugin](http://sgeek.org/create-jquery-plugin/)

**Original answer** [Here i want to suggest steps to create simple plugin with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36467948/2689199)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Node.js installed you can use [create-jquery-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-jquery-plugin) CLI utility. Just run

```sh
npx create-jquery-plugin
```

Or, you can clone the [jquery-plugin-boilerplate](https://github.com/techlab/jquery-plugin-boilerplate)
to get started.