# call javascript / jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, slider

I am using the following javascript which uses some jQuery, neither of which I know much about. This is for a simple image slider:

```
/*!
 * jQuery wmuSlider v2.1
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2011 Brice Lechatellier
 * http://brice.lechatellier.com/
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

;(function($) {

$.fn.wmuSlider = function(options) {

    /* Default Options
    ================================================== */       
    var defaults = {
        animation: 'fade',
        animationDuration: 600,
        slideshow: true,
        slideshowSpeed: 7000,
        slideToStart: 0,
        navigationControl: true,
        paginationControl: true,
        previousText: 'Previous',
        nextText: 'Next',
        touch: false,
        slide: 'article',
        items: 1
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        /* Variables
        ================================================== */
        var $this = $(this);
        var currentIndex = options.slideToStart;
        var wrapper = $this.find('.wmuSliderWrapper');
        var slides = $this.find(options.slide);
        var slidesCount = slides.length;
        var slideshowTimeout;
        var paginationControl;
        var isAnimating;


        /* Load Slide
        ================================================== */ 
        var loadSlide = function(index, infinite, touch) {
            if (isAnimating) {
                return false;
            }
            isAnimating = true;
            currentIndex = index;
            var slide = $(slides[index]);
            $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
            if (options.animation == 'fade') {
                slides.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    opacity: 0
                });
                slide.css('position', 'relative');
                slide.animate({ opacity:1 }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                    isAnimating = false;
                });
            } else if (options.animation == 'slide') {
                if (!infinite) {
                    wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * index }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                        isAnimating = false;
                    });
                } else {
                    if (index == 0) {
                        wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * slidesCount }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                            wrapper.css('marginLeft', 0);
                            isAnimating = false;
                        });
                    } else {
                        if (!touch) {
                            wrapper.css('marginLeft', -$this.width() / options.items * slidesCount);
                        }
                        wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * index }, options.animationDuration, function() {
                            isAnimating = false;
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            if (paginationControl) {
                paginationControl.find('a').each(function(i) {
                    if(i == index) {
                        $(this).addClass('wmuActive');
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass('wmuActive');
                    }
                });
            }    

            // Trigger Event
            $this.trigger('slideLoaded', index);             
        };


        /* Navigation Control
        ================================================== */ 
        if (options.navigationControl) {
            var prev = $('<a class="wmuSliderPrev">' + options.previousText + '</a>');
            prev.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
                if (currentIndex == 0) {
                    loadSlide(slidesCount - 1, true);
                } else {
                    loadSlide(currentIndex - 1);
                }
            });
            $this.append(prev);

            var next = $('<a class="wmuSliderNext">' + options.nextText + '</a>');
            next.click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
                if (currentIndex + 1 == slidesCount) {    
                    loadSlide(0, true);
                } else {
                    loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
                }
            });                
            $this.append(next);
        }


        /* Pagination Control
        ================================================== */ 
        if (options.paginationControl) {
            paginationControl = $('<ul class="wmuSliderPagination"></ul>');
            $.each(slides, function(i) {
                paginationControl.append('<li><a href="#">' + i + '</a></li>');
                paginationControl.find('a:eq(' + i + ')').click(function(e) {    
                    e.preventDefault();
                    clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);   
                    loadSlide(i);
                });                
            });
            $this.append(paginationControl);
        }


        /* Slideshow
        ================================================== */ 
        if (options.slideshow) {
            var slideshow = function() {
                if (currentIndex + 1 < slidesCount) {
                    loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
                } else {
                    loadSlide(0, true);
                }
                slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(slideshow, options.slideshowSpeed);
            }
            slideshowTimeout = setTimeout(slideshow, options.slideshowSpeed);
        }


        /* Resize Slider
        ================================================== */ 
        var resize = function() {
            var slide = $(slides[currentIndex]);
            $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
            if (options.animation == 'slide') {
                slides.css({
                    width: $this.width() / options.items
                });
                wrapper.css({
                    marginLeft: -$this.width() / options.items * currentIndex,
                    width: $this.width() * slides.length
                });                    
            }    
        };


        /* Touch
        ================================================== */
        var touchSwipe = function(event, phase, direction, distance) {
            clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);              
            if(phase == 'move' && (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right')) {
                if (direction == 'right') {
                    if (currentIndex == 0) {
                        wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-slidesCount * $this.width() / options.items) + distance);
                    } else {
                        wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items) + distance);
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'left') {
                    wrapper.css('marginLeft', (-currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items) - distance);
                }
            } else if (phase == 'cancel' ) {
                if (direction == 'right' && currentIndex == 0) {
                    wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -slidesCount * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);                
                } else {
                    wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);  
                }
            } else if (phase == 'end' ) {
                if (direction == 'right') {
                    if (currentIndex == 0) {
                        loadSlide(slidesCount - 1, true, true);
                    } else {
                        loadSlide(currentIndex - 1);
                    }
                } else if (direction == 'left')    {        
                    if (currentIndex + 1 == slidesCount) {
                        loadSlide(0, true);
                    } else {
                        loadSlide(currentIndex + 1);
                    }
                } else {
                    wrapper.animate({ marginLeft: -currentIndex * $this.width() / options.items }, options.animationDuration);
                }
            }            
        };
        if (options.touch && options.animation == 'slide') {
            if (!$.isFunction($.fn.swipe)) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'jquery.touchSwipe.min.js',
                    async: false
                });
            }
            if ($.isFunction($.fn.swipe)) {
                $this.swipe({ triggerOnTouchEnd:false, swipeStatus:touchSwipe, allowPageScroll:'vertical' });
            }
        }


        /* Init Slider
        ================================================== */ 
        var init = function() {
            var slide = $(slides[currentIndex]);
            var img = slide.find('img');
            img.load(function() {
                wrapper.show();
                $this.animate({ height: slide.innerHeight() });
            });
            if (options.animation == 'fade') {
                slides.css({
                    position: 'absolute',
                    width: '100%',
                    opacity: 0
                });
                $(slides[currentIndex]).css('position', 'relative');
            } else if (options.animation == 'slide') {
                if (options.items > slidesCount) {
                    options.items = slidesCount;
                }
                slides.css('float', 'left');                    
                slides.each(function(i){
                    var slide = $(this);
                    slide.attr('data-index', i);
                });
                for(var i = 0; i < options.items; i++) {
                    wrapper.append($(slides[i]).clone());
                }
                slides = $this.find(options.slide);
            }
            resize();

            $this.trigger('hasLoaded');

            loadSlide(currentIndex);
        }
        init();


        /* Bind Events
        ================================================== */
        // Resize
        $(window).resize(resize);

        // Load Slide
        $this.bind('loadSlide', function(e, i) {
            clearTimeout(slideshowTimeout);
            loadSlide(i);
        });

    });
}

})(jQuery);
```

what I want to be able to do is change the slider image index with some sort of 'onclick' event. for example:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadSlide(3, false);"><img src="images/IMG_5137_s.jpg" width="100%" /></a>
```

this however does not call the 'loadslide' function in the javascript file, probably because I don't know what I'm doing.... any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338967/jquery-issue-on-extending-jquery-functionality/11339046#11339046

Comment: loadSlide function is private. Follow @barlasapaydin link

Comment: I see, thats what I figured, Im looking at that link now, I see I can figure it out in a bit...

Comment: @user1576497 i wrote it as an answer too, ask if you don't understand any point.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect this answer for jQuery plugin-authoring:
[How to create simple jQuery plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338967/jquery-issue-on-extending-jquery-functionality/11339046#11339046)

And here is the simple [jsFiddle example with explanation on it](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/5yKr6/6/).

Comment: I tried many things but I dont understand enough.  I played with it in jsFiddle... I still dont understand how to call 'loadSlide' or send it the index for the image I want loaded.

Comment: I dont quite understand the javascript, I can't tell how/what functions are being defined here and I dont know how the 'this' pointer works or what it's doing...

Comment: I tried adding:
    var button = $('a', $this);
    button.click(loadSlide(options.slideChange));
 
    $(function () {
    $('#plugin').YourPluginName({
        slideChange: 3
    });
    });

Comment: oops, according to your example all it should take is, 2 lines:
var button = $('a', $this);
button.click(loadSlide(3, true));

Comment: @user1576497 this represent's selector at user's document definition. in this example it represets = $('#plugin')

Comment: mate you need to be at some good level on javascript to create a plugin, if you are new at js, i suggest improve your js at http://www.codecademy.com/

Comment: uhhh hmmm thats too basic i know HOW to program i just dont know javascript or anything about the jquery libraries... anyone who knows js ought to be able to figure this out very quickly - define a link on the page as a variable then use myvar.click function to call the loadSlide function already in the plugin and boom