# Jquery plugin $.fn.myplugin not working

Tags: jquery, plugins

I might be making a very simple mistake but am having some serious trouble tring to figure out why it's not working.

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/HthCa/

UPDATE: this is my actual code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#test').customTabs();
    })
</script>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert($(this).html());
}
```

Comment: for simple jQuery plugin structure, this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338967/issue-on-extending-functionality-on-a-simple-jquery-plugin/11339046#11339046

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
$('#test').customTabs();

$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert($(this).html());
};
```

You're calling `$.fn.customTabs()` before defining it. Try instead:

```
$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert(this.html());
};

$('#test').customTabs();
```

Note that you do not need to apply `$` to `this` in a plugin method, as `this` is already a jQuery object (the one on which the method was called).

Comment: Thanks! Take a look at my update of my actual code on my site. They are in the correct order..

Comment: @Noah, I suppose you're including jQuery before `scripts.js`? Can you post the exact error message you receive?

Comment: Yes there is a call to jquery before I call scrips.js. I'm on my iPad using the Koder app to do this and I'm not getting any errors. I set up alerts before and after to check where the error is happening and it is happening at the call to the plugin.

Comment: @Noah, sorry, I'm confused: are you `not getting any errors` or are you getting one `at the call to the plugin`?

Comment: And these are all in the head of the HTML page

Comment: I'm not able to see if I'm getting any errors cause the app doesn't have a function that shows if there are any. But i know that there is one cause all the JavaScript works up to the point of the plugin call

Comment: Then can you put an `alert($.fn.customTabs);` in the global scope at the end of `scripts.js` and check if it runs and what it prints?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15983/discussion-between-noah-passalacqua-and-frederic-hamidi)

Answer (score 1):

Put the new function definition above where you call it.

```
$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert($(this).html());
};
$('#test').customTabs();
```

Answer (score 1):

put your code like this

```
$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert($(this).html());
};
$('#test').customTabs();
```

or

```
$.fn.customTabs = function() {
    alert($(this).html());
};
$(function() { // <-- inside a dom ready
    $('#test').customTabs();
});​
```

The cause was you tried to use a function that wasn't defined yet as stated in the console
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'customTabs'`

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you accessing it from jquery selector object like this

```
$("some selectors").myPlugin()
```

if you tried this

```
$.myPlugin() // it won't work
```

it won't work