# Method for jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to make a jQuery plugin for custom checkboxes and radio buttons.

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.checkboxRadio = function(options)
    {
        var defaults = some;
        ...

        return this.each(function()
        {
            var button = $(this);
            ...
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

It can be used now by `$('input').checkboxRadio(options);`

How do I add a method `check` without changing current scope, to make a possible usage of something like `$('input').checkboxRadio('check')`?

How to handle a custom method and get its name inside my plugin?

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11339046/1428241

Comment: Thanks, but that solution has no methods.

Comment: In addition - I would like to keep current code style, with no usage of `$.extend`

Comment: you can write a switch in to plugin and gave chanse to choose users from defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the official [jquery plugin guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

The part about wrapping functions is found [here ("Plugin Methods")](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Plugin_Methods) (the example is a would-be tooltip plugin) :

```
(function( $ ){
  var methods = {
    init : function(options) { ... },
    show : function() { ... },
    hide : function() { ... },
    update : function(content) { ... }
  };

  $.fn.tooltip = function( method ) {

    // Method calling logic
    if ( methods[method] ) {
      return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
    } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
      return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
    } else {
      $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
    }    
  };
})(jQuery);
```

---

**[update]** explaining the `methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ))` line in the guide :

If you call `$(selector).tooltip('update', 'hello')` from your javascript code, you want to end up calling the `update` method, passing `'hello'` as the `content` argument, with `this` set to `$(selector)` for the duration of the call.

That is what this line takes care of :

- if `method == 'update'`, `methods[method]` is the `update` method,
- `arguments` will be equal to `['update', 'hello']`, you have to drop the first element to get the arguments you want to pass to your method ; this is exactly what `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)` does,
- `myFunc.apply(obj, argsArray)` calls the function `myFunc`, passing `argsArray` as the arguments, and setting `this` to `obj` for the duration of the call.

So inside your methods, you can call `this.each(...)` to iterate over all of the selector's items, e.g. :

```
update: function(content) {
  this.each(function(){ $(this).data('tooltip.content', content); });
  return this;
}
```

Comment: I've seen that. What about options var and each?

Comment: Not sure what we're doing by this code `methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ))`

Comment: Where all the logic goes (.each, etc), if there is no method `show/hide/update`? Seems `init` will be used instead - how do I use `each` inside it, to handle each input of the target object?

Comment: So the question for this solution is, how do I get `this` of `$.fn.tooltip` inside current methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect plugin methods like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.checkboxRadio = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            check: 'check'
    }

        return this.each(function() {
            var o = options;
            var _this = $(this);

            if( o.check === 'check' ) {
                 _this.attr('checked','checked');
            }else if ( o.check === 'uncheck' ) {
                 _this.removeAttr('checked');
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

and user document should be like what you want: `$('input').checkboxRadio({check:'check'});`

Comment: this seems to be not a right solution, because start options would be overwritten. To use it, I have to give all the other options with conjunction of "check: check".

Comment: @Steve i am trying to explain the logic of this, you can edit the values/functions whatever you like.

Comment: There is a way to read `check` and if it exists, do something without call of the other options. But, it's not a solution I would like to see in my plugin, thanks anyway.