# How can I embed a function call inside another function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have the following code: and I want to call

## preloadfunction()

```
  (function ($) {
 $.fn.waterwheelCarousel = function (options) {
 options = $.extend({}, $.fn.waterwheelCarousel.defaults, options || {});

    return $(this).each(function () {
 var data = {
        itemsContainer:         $(this).find(".carousel-images"),
        totalItems:             $(this).find(".carousel-images img").length,
        containerWidth:         $(this).width(),
        containerHeight:        $(this).height(),
        currentCenterItem:      null,
        items:                  [],
        itemDistances:          [],
        waveDistances:          [],
        itemWidths:             [],
        itemHeights:            [],
        itemOpacities:          [],
        carouselRotationsLeft:  0,
        currentlyMoving:        false,
        itemsAnimating:         0,
        currentSpeed:           options.speed,
        intervalTimer:          null
      };

      // Setup the carousel
      beforeLoaded();
      // Preload the images. Once they are preloaded, the passed in function
      // will be called and the carousel will be setup
      preload(function () {
        setupDistanceArrays();
        setupCarousel();
        setupStarterRotation();
      });
```

I have tried :

`waterwheelCarousel().preloadfunction()` and it's give me undefined method

also I have tried :

```
var t = $("#waterwheelcarouseldefault").waterwheelCarousel(); 
t.preloadfunction();
```

with no luck any one knows how to call this function?

Comment: You should have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods

Answer (score 2):

Isn't the function called "preload", and not "preloadfunction"?

Have you tried

```
waterwheelCarousel().preload();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create an object of your structure this way the code will get more readable. for example:

```
var app = 
{
      // Setup the carousel
      beforeLoaded : beforeLoaded(),
      preload: function () {
        setupDistanceArrays();
        setupCarousel();
        setupStarterRotation();
      }

 };
```

this way you can access your function by typing `app.preload();`

Comment: SHOULD I PUT VAR APP BEFORE (function ($) { WHICH IS THE FIRST STATEMNT IN MY CASE