# JS initiating correctly, but still won't run unless I put it into the console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this running after I have output my markup (just before the `</body>`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
.....
    focusLeaving: function(){
                    e('#running');
                    $('.levelThree').on('mouseleave',function () {
                        e('remove');
                        MM.internalMenu.levelFive.close(function(){});
                        MM.internalMenu.levelThree.close($(this));
                        $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
                    });
                }
    //This outputs as expect: '#running'
....
});
```

However leaving a `.levelThree` nothing will happen. If I run the above code inside the console or even run the function itself via the console `MM.internalMenu.levelThree.focusLeaving();` the the function works accordingly.

This is confused me no end, I know it should work. I even know its running, so why won't it work....

Comment: Where does the `MM` come from? What frameworks/libraries are you using apart from jQuery?

Comment: Only jQuery running. MM is just a `object` that i have created to hold all of my functions etc. `var MM = {};`

Comment: looks like timing, try adding some kind of dom ready callback and execute your code there.

Comment: Do you see any error on console?

Comment: My thoughts exactly, however i have already wrapped it with `.ready()`

Comment: @JamieHutber Then perhaps this object `MM` is in the local scope of `.ready()`'s anonymous function.

Comment: can you post the html so we can see the order you are loading your scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `on` function means you are binding an event to a callback handler. `$('.levelThree').on('mouseleave',function () { .... }` equates to saying "From now on, when a mouseleave event is triggered on the item, do this function".

The function itself will not be executed at that point in time, it will only be **set up** to execute when a mouseleave event occurs.

To explain further:

```
<a id="my_link" href="#"> click me! </a>
```

When you click this, not much happens. Suppose you want it to say `You clicked me!` when you click on it. You'll need to set it up using the `on` function.

```
$("#my_link").on('click', function {
    alert("You clicked me!");
});
```

Note that you still haven't seen an alert box with the message. You have only **set up** the alert box to be shown on a click.
If you click the link, *only then* will you see the alert box.

What's important to note is that setting up an event handler does not trigger the event itself. However, if you run that code in the console, it **will be directly executed**. That explains why your code is working when run in the console.

I assume the `focusLeaving` is an event that fires when a mouse leaves the item? In that case, the easiest way to fix this is by removing the `on` function, as there is already an event firing and executing. You're setting it up twice, which is what causing the issue you're facing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was slightly embarrassed to comment further once I realised that my `.on` was not set up correctly. Still got it working and felt dirty

Answer (score 0):

Have you wrapped your script in `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`? By running your JS functions after the DOM is ready will probably make your script work again, assuming that `MM` has been defined.

According to the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the
>   DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other
>   event handlers and run other jQuery code

Comment: @JamieHutber I suspect that you're not declaring the method properly. What about using `$.fn.extend({ focusLeave: { ... } });` See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods