# create a JQuery Plugin with value getter/setter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

**I need a result, like this:**

getter

```
$('selector').myplugin().val();
```

setter

```
$('selector').myplugin().val('value');
```

**and i don't want result like this:**

```
$('selector').myplugin({ value: 'value' });
```

or

```
$('selector').myplugin('setValue', 'value');
```

**start to define plugin:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.myplugin= function () {
        return this.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        ...
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

this question - [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods) not help..

Comment: Your use of `val()` in this instance is confusing and you should not be trying to overwrite jquery behaviour imo. The linked question is correct and almost all plugins I have seen work in this way.

Comment: @jammykam thanks. I think i should define plugin - `$('selector').myplugin();` And then set/get value like this - `$('selector').val();`/`$('selector').val("value");` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin code sets and gets a value in a jQuery plugin.

```
;(function($) {

    var myValue;

    $.myplugin = {

        myValue: function(value) {

            if (typeof(value) != "undefined") {
                myValue = value;
            } else {
                return myValue;
            }

        }

    }

})(jQuery);


jQuery.myplugin.myValue("test");
alert($.myplugin.myValue());

jQuery.myplugin.myValue(10);
alert($.myplugin.myValue());
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ypE28/

Comment: Multiple instances of your plugin will share the share `myValue` property. That may be the intention here, but usually it is not. You need to scope the variable.