# Confused by 'bootstrap-slider' jQuery plugin architecture

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I am quite new to jQuery plugins and I don't understand the architecture of the [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider/blob/master/js/bootstrap-slider.js) plugin.

What is actually returned when you create the slider?

```
var mySlider = $('.slider').slider({...});
```

I would expect the Slider class (object) but I can not access it's methods directly, instead I have to do this:

```
mySlider.slider('setValue',4);
```

Why should I call Slider's methods as string and not directly? What I would expect is:

```
var mySlider = $('.slider').slider({...});?
mySlider.setValue(4);
```

Again I am new to this, is it some kind of ugly pattern or did I understand it wrongly? Can someone please explain it please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the architecture was inspired by [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods).

IMHO this is very bad architecture. It is error prone, can not be strong typed (with TypeScript) or checked for integrity at compile time. There is a reason we don't write code in strings.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can calling an anonymous jQuery function on a selector.  When you call $('.slider') you are creating a jQuery object where the methods and parameters are stored.

JQuery plugin patterns is a great place to start.  I would checkout this article by @addyosmani
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/