# Javascript - Change FullCalendar.js callback after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I am trying to extend functionality of the [FullCalender](http://fullcalendar.io/) JS plugin. I am quite new to javascript OOP concepts as well as jQuery plugin development. In a first step I am wondering how to use and access the FullCalendar plugin. The `fullCalendar` method can be called on any DOM Element while the calendar parameters can be given as JSON object:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
    editable: true,             // a parameter  
    events: "./events.php",     // some events

    eventRender: function(event, element) {     // a callback
        // do something here
    }
});
```

I tried calling this creation method again and change the callback `eventRender` but it does not work. I guess its because the calendar allows only one instance active on the DOM element. But how can I change parameters and callbacks without destroying and recreating the calendar?

Furthermore I tried to access the calendar object directly but I guess due to encapsulation it is not exposed through the FullCalendar. In contrast I see that the `fullCalendar` function can be called with a string specifying a method to be called on the Calendar. Is this a common mechanism on plugin encapsulation?

Comment: what is your goal with regard to needing to change eventRenderer?

Comment: The callback was just an example for me, of how to change the calendar instance I have just created. But that does not seem to be a valid practice in this case.

Comment: as with many plugins there is a destroy method also http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/destroy/ so if you needed to change behaviors you could initialize again with different config

Comment: Yes I've noticed the destroy method but as I stated in my question I hoped for a different way than destroy/recreation. My problem seems to be thinking the C++/Java OOP way, where you create an instance and than have methods to change properties. But in javascript plugin context this is different here.

Comment: not always, it depends on the plugin. SOme have ways to change options on the fly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first part, FullCalendar merges the options during initialization

```
var options = mergeOptions({}, defaults, instanceOptions);
```

so you can only change `eventRender` by

```
var currentHandler

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
eventRender: function(event, element) {     // a callback
    currentHandler(event, element)
}
});
```

and then change `currentHandler` implementation (i.e. `currentHandler = myFirstHandler`)

When it comes to calling plugin methods, yes this is a common practice and was described here [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods)

Comment: Yes I supposed this way to change the handler, but I hoped there would be another way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead `eventRender` I would use the official `eventAfterAllRender` callback, see [docs](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/).

```
        // hide div after fullcalendar has initialized
        eventAfterAllRender: function(view)
        {
            $('.mycustomdiv').hide();
        }
```

This is kind of hidden in the docs. Would be better to rename this function to afterinit or alike.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what version of fullcalendar you were using at the time of posting, but for anyone looking now with v2 or v3, fullcalendar has [on/off](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/handlers/) and [get/set](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/) utilities that allow you to add/remove handler functions or get/set options dynamically after init.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/handlers/

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/dynamic_options/

According to the docs:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getCalendar');

calendar.on('eventRender', function(event, element, view) {
  console.log('event rendered!', event);
});
```