# How To Create methods(functions) in jQuery Plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a plugin, which will be looking for a `img` file on PC, and after load this image file, the user can choose some methods to apply in this. For example, in a call plugin:

```
$('#test').myPlugin({
  legend: true
});
```

And my code for plugin upload a file is this:

```
    (function( $ ){
var handleFileSelect = function (evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    for(var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
              // Render thumbnail.
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = ['<img class="responsive-img thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
              document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
};
$.fn.upload = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend( {}, options );
    return this.each(function() {
        document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
    });
};
})( jQuery );
```

This code works fine on upload `img`, but I don´t have idea, how I can add methods in this plugin. Someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how i can add methods in this plugin

The same way that you *already do*.  Notice how you're adding a plugin function here:

```
$.fn.upload = function(options) {
    //...
}
```

So if you want to add a function by a different name, simply add a function by a different name:

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
    //...
}
```