# How to access properties and functions of a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.my_custom_jquery_plugin = function() {
        var custom_settings = {
            first: 'First',
            second: 'Second'
        }

        function a_custom_function() {
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I would like to know how I can access the settings variable and a_custom_function function from outside the plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the objects `data` to store your settings:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.my_custom_jquery_plugin = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            first: 'First',
            second: 'Second'
        }, options );
        
        // this points to $('#test') in this example
        this.data("settings", settings)
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#test').my_custom_jquery_plugin({first: 'NotFirst'});
console.log($('#test').data("settings"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
```

Also note that jQuery suggest that you use the minimum possible function names in the global namespace, so if you are just starting your plugin consider using the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871820/3727050).