# How can I get the date format from an initialized Bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following bootstrap datepicker:

```
<input type="dtpicker" id="abc" name="abc" value="26-05-2022">

$('input[type="dtpicker"]').datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    clearBtn: true,
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom right",
    autoUpdateInput: true
});
```

How can I get "format" option by code (either Javascript or jQuery)?

Generally, how can I get datepicker options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(element).data().datepicker.o.format
```

See [How to access properties and functions of a jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135809/how-to-access-properties-and-functions-of-a-jquery-plugin/72397419#72397419).