# How to create a javascript plugin with methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

From [How to create a jQuery plugin with methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117086/how-to-create-a-jquery-plugin-with-methods)

How to do the same thing in javascript **Without JQuery**

**JQuery**

```
    (function ( $ ) {
 
    $.fn.greenify = function() {
        this.css( "color", "green" );
        return this;
    };
 
}( jQuery ));
```

**Js**

```
?
```

Comment: What do yo mean by "the same thing"? You mean adding methods to DOM elements?

Comment: @Nithish unfortunately TJ has guided you into the trap he points out. there are many techniques available to you that prevent tampering with native prototypes. i don't know why he neglected to demonstrate those. i asked but he didn't care to offer an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean "how do I add my own methods to DOM element," my recommendation is: Don't, because your methods can conflict with ones added to the standard later. (And *absolutely* don't in a library, only do it — if you do it — in code for a specific page or application.) Instead, do what jQuery did and put wrappers around elements.

But if you want to do it anyway, you'd add functions to the prototype of the elements you want them to appear on. The base HTML element is `HTMLElement`, so to add a method to all HTML elements, you'd add it there.

```
// Ensure that your method isn't enumerable by using `Object.defineProperty`
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "greenify", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value() {
        this.style.color = "green";
    }
});
```

Example:

```js
// Ensure that your method isn't enumerable by using `Object.defineProperty`
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, "greenify", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value() {
        this.style.color = "green";
    }
});

// Use it
document.getElementById("a").greenify();
document.getElementById("b").greenify();

// Since it's on the prototype, it applies regardless of
// whether the element already existed:
const c = document.createElement("div");
c.greenify();
c.textContent = `This is "c"`;
document.body.appendChild(c);
```

```html
<div id="a">This is "a"</div>
<div id="b">This is "b"</div>
```

For now, collections of elements are either `NodeList` instances (`querySelectorAll` and other newer collections) or `HTMLCollection` instances (`getElementsByXYZ`), although that may evolve further. So if you wanted to be able to call `addClass` on a collection, you'd add it to one or both of those prototypes. Let's move from `greenify` to a more useful example: Adding a class to all elements in the collection:

```js
// Ensure that your method isn't enumerable by using `Object.defineProperty`
function addClass(...classes) {
    for (let n = 0; n < this.length; ++n) {
        this[n].classList.add(...classes);
    }
}
Object.defineProperty(NodeList.prototype, "addClass", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: addClass
});
Object.defineProperty(HTMLCollection.prototype, "addClass", {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: addClass
});

// Use it
document.querySelectorAll("div").addClass("accent");
document.getElementsByClassName("x").addClass("emphasize");
```

```css
.accent {
    color: green;
}
.emphasize {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">This is "a"</div>
<div class="x">This is "b"</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**plain old functions**

jQuery is nothing more than JavaScript itself. You could easily write `greenify` and `boldify` as plain functions. This is a good approach because each simple function is easy to write, test, and reuse in any part of your program that needs this specific behaviour -

```js
function greenify (elem) {
  elem.style.color = "green"
}

function boldify (elem) {
  elem.style.fontWeight = "bold"
}

greenify(document.querySelector("#foo"))
boldify(document.querySelector("#bar"))
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

| *html render: example 1* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-1] |

---

**classes and caveats**

jQuery uses an object-oriented style which allows for "chaining" of methods. This interface is desirable because it enables us to write programs as long chained expressions, much like we can write sentences. Most people would accomplish this using a `class`, which is syntactic sugar for defining a function and adding "methods" to the function's [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) -

```js
class MyTools {
  constructor (elem) {
    this.elem = elem
  }
  greenify() {
    this.elem.style.color = "green"
    return this
  }
  boldify() {
    this.elem.style.fontWeight = "bold"
    return this
  }
}

function mytools (elem) {
  return new MyTools(elem) 
}

mytools(document.querySelector("#foo")).greenify()
mytools(document.querySelector("#bar")).boldify()
mytools(document.querySelector("#qux")).boldify().greenify()
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

| *html render: example 2* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-2] |

But what if we had a lot of methods like `greenify` and `boldify` in our `mytools` class? You can see how the class could become quite large, and repeating `return this` for every method is a bit of burden. And what if someone wanted to use just *part* of your tool library in the future? Using a monolithic class makes it impossible to use [dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_shaking), meaning the entire module must be included even if **one** function is needed.

---

**higher-order functions**

Can we build an intuitive interface without such drawbacks? One approach to address these issues is to use [higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). Such a function can take a function as input and/or return a new function as output. You may have used built-in higher-order functions like `Array.prototype.map`, `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.reduce`, or others, but we can easily make our own, too -

```js
const effect = f =>
  x => { f(x); return x }

function identity (value) {
  return { value, map: f => identity(f(value)) }
}

const boldify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = "bold")

const greenify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = "green")

// prefix style; ordinary function calls
greenify(boldify(document.querySelector("#foo")))

// "chaining" style; by use of identity
identity(document.querySelector("#qux"))
  .map(boldify)
  .map(greenify)
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

| *html render: example 3* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-3] |

---

**modules**

Even the "slim" version of jQuery 3.6.0 is over **72 KB**, and there's no way to import just a piece of it. This is a consequence of how jQuery choose to implement everything through a single object-oriented interface, the `jQuery` function, aliased as `$`. However the future of JavaScript lies in its design for [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). They are reusable, flexible, and can be loaded on-the-fly, resulting in highly-optimized and streamlined scripts that are instantly ready to respond to the user.

We've written a few functions above. Let's see how we might start to organize the modules for our own program -

```js
// func.js

function identity (value) {
  return { value, map: f => identity(f(value)) }
}

const effect = f =>
  x => { f(x); return x }


export { effect, identity }
```

```js
// css.js

import { effect } from "./func.js"

const boldify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = "bold")

const greenify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = "green")

export { boldify, greenify }
```

When we use a module, we `import` only the parts we need. This gives the compiler (transpiler, "packer", "bundler", etc) an opportunity to remove dead code and dramatically cut down the size of a completed production-ready program -

```js
// main
import { greenify } from "./css.js"

greenify(document.querySelector("#some-elem"))
```

Even `*` imports can be optimized as a dependency resolver can determine only particular functions from the `css`-named import are used -

```js
import { identity } from "./func.js"
import * as css from "./css.js"

identity(document.querySelector("#some-elem"))
  .map(css.boldify)
  .map(css.greenify)
```

---

**growing your modules**

So you want to expand your module to support some other colours, like `bluify`, `purplify`, and more. You might try something like this -

```js
// css.js
// DON'T DO THIS!

const bluify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = "green")

const greenify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = "green")

const purplify =
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = "purplify")

// ...

export { bluify, greenify, purplify, ... }
```

Instead, notice how only the `...` portion of `elem.style.color = ...` changes in each function. To avoid repeating ourself over and over, we make functions -

```js
// css.js

import { effect } from "./func.js"

// any color, not just green!
const color = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = value)

// any font-weight, not just bold!
const fontWeight = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = value)
  
// other CSS properties...
const fontSize = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontSize = value)

// ...

export { color, fontWeight, fontSize, ... }
```

Notice how `color`, `fontWeight` and `fontSize` each have a `value` parameter. We reduced code duplication and made our functions more useful -

```js
// main.js

import { identity } from "./func.js"
import * as css from "./css.js"

identity(document.querySelector("#bar"))
  .map(css.color("limegreen"))
  .map(css.fontSize("24pt"))
  
identity(document.querySelector("#qux"))
  .map(css.color("dodgerblue"))
  .map(css.fontWeight("900"))
```

| *html render: example 4* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-4] |

Expand snippet 4 below to verify this result in your own browser -

```js
// func.js
const effect = f =>
  x => { f(x); return x }

function identity (value) {
  return { value, map: f => identity(f(value)) }
}

// css.js
const fontWeight = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = value)
  
const fontSize = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontSize = value)

const color = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = value)

// main.js
identity(document.querySelector("#bar"))
  .map(color("limegreen"))
  .map(fontSize("24pt"))
  
identity(document.querySelector("#qux"))
  .map(color("dodgerblue"))
  .map(fontWeight("900"))
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

---

**jQuery Lite**

Maybe you like jQuery because it accepts a CSS selector and doesn't require you to use `identity` or `document.querySelector`. jQuery made a choice and so can you. It's your program and you're free to invent any convenience you desire -

```js
// myquery.js

import { identity } from "./func.js"

function $(selector) {
  const loop = t => plugin => loop(t.map(plugin))
  return loop(identity(document.querySelector(selector)))
}

export { $ }
```

We can start to see our very own `$` evolving! -

```js
// main.js

import { $ } from "./myquery.js"
import { color, fontSize, fontWeight } from "./css.js"

// example expressions
$("#bar")(color("gold"))(fontSize("8pt"))

$("#qux")(fontSize("14pt"))(color("hotpink"))(fontWeight(900))
```

| *html render: example 5* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-5] |

Expand snippet 5 below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
// func.js
const effect = f =>
  x => { f(x); return x }

function identity (value) {
  return { value, map: f => identity(f(value)) }
}

// css.js
const fontWeight = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = value)
  
const fontSize = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontSize = value)

const color = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = value)
  
// myquery.js
function $(selector) {
  const loop = t => plugin => loop(t.map(plugin))
  return loop(identity(document.querySelector(selector)))
}

// main.js
$("#bar")(color("gold"))(fontSize("8pt"))
$("#qux")(fontSize("14pt"))(color("hotpink"))(fontWeight(900))
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

Maybe you would like to operate on multiple elements, similar to jQuery? We can do that by using `querySelectorAll` and apply `plugin` to all elements in an iterable using `Array.from`. Note we also can bypass the need for `identity` as `loop` already [closes over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) its `context` -

```js
// myquery.js (updated)

function $(selector) {
  const loop = context => plugin => loop(Array.from(context, plugin))
  return loop(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
}
```

```js
// main.js

// target all <p> elements
$("p")(color("orchid"))

// target #foo element
$("#foo")(fontSize("18pt"))(fontWeight("bold"))

// target #bar and #qux elements
$("#bar,#qux")(fontSize("12pt"))
```

| *html render: example 6* |
| --- |
| [image: render-preview-6] |

Expand snippet 6 below to verify the results in your browser -

```js
// func.js
const effect = f =>
  x => { f(x); return x }

function identity (value) {
  return { value, map: f => identity(f(value)) }
}

// css.js
const fontWeight = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontWeight = value)
  
const fontSize = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.fontSize = value)

const color = value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style.color = value)
  
// myquery.js
function $(selector) {
  const loop = t => plugin => loop(t.map(v => Array.from(v, plugin)))
  return loop(identity(document.querySelectorAll(selector)))
}

// main.js
$("p")(color("orchid"))
$("#foo")(fontSize("18pt"))(fontWeight("bold"))
$("#bar,#qux")(fontSize("12pt"))
```

```html
<p id="foo">hello world</p>
<p id="bar">hello world</p>
<p id="qux">hello world</p>
```

---

**eagle eyes**

Did you notice how `color`, `fontWeight`, and `fontSize` looked almost exactly the same? We can continue to use abstraction to remove additional duplication. By capturing the smallest identifiable essence of a behaviour, we gain the most flexibility, allowing us to easily build sophisticated behaviours from simple ones -

```js
// css.js

import { effect } from "./func.js"

const style = property => value =>
  effect(elem => elem.style[property] = value)

const color = style("color")
const fontWeight = style("fontWeight")
const fontSize = style("fontSize")

// ...

export { color, fontWeight, fontSize, style, ... }
```

Comment: This plug-in mechanism is beautiful!  I can easily see applying it in many other scenarios.

Comment: thanks @Scott. i think modules might be the best thing to happen to JS since its inception. my only complaint is they're not first-class! maybe in 10 years or so haha

Comment: Beautifully written answer, a blog article in itself!